# How do I convert an expression that is a function of some variables into a functional?

Tags: functions, function-construction, scoping

If I have an arbitrary `f[x, y, z]`, how do I convert it to `f[#1, #2, #3] &` without messing up scopes or causing scope leakage?

Note: I want to generalize this into a generic form, e.g. `MakeFunction[exp_, args__]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is deceptively simple:

```
MakeFunction[exp_, args___] = Function[{args}, exp]; SetAttributes[MakeFunction, HoldFirst];
```

Now if you say:

```
MakeFunction[Sin[x + y], x, y];
```

You get:

```
Function[{x, y}, Sin[x + y]]
```